# Negation of a statement: No human can fly

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

We have the statement: No human can fly.
I know that the negation of it is: One human can fly.
But i'm not sure why this is true, because it seems more logical to say that at least one human can fly. In this case I described all the other possibilites as well not only the case where only one human can fly.

Comment: Actually, the negation is "at least one human can fly" or "there exists a human that can fly" (or "a human can fly", but in mathematical writing without clear context, maybe avoid this).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Why isn't the negation "at least one human cannot fly"? Sorry if this sounds dumb, I have arid memories about those things. I have been taught, at times, that in addition to $\exists$ and $\forall$ negation, one must act on the phrase/consequence itself. Do I remember wrong?

Comment: Some human can fly.

Comment: @KurtGödel The original statement is "no human can fly", that is, "there does not exist a human, who can fly", or symbolically, $\neg\exists h\,F(h)$. Given the rule $\neg \exists x\phi\iff \forall x \neg\phi$, you should be able to see how your statement, equivalent to $\exists h \neg F(h)$, is not implied. In particular, we could have $\exists h \neg F(h)$ *without* necessarily $\forall h \neg F(h)$.

Comment: @Jam Oh that's now clear, thank you!

Comment: "No human can fly" = "All humans cannot fly" = "Some humans can fly" (negating the 'All' quantifier into the 'Some', and negating 'cannot' into 'can').

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My original answer was:

> Those are both correct. In mathematics “one” means “at least one” unless prefaced by “exactly.”

Some may disagree, including the esteemed Prof. Doktor Gödel below. To me, in this context, *one* is synonymous with *a(n)*, the indefinite article.

Perhaps this is evidence that one (meaning *you* in this context) should avoid ambiguity and use *some* or *at least one*.

Comment: I disagree with this. In Mathematics, one means one. Othewise you specify "at least" one, "one and only one", "more than" one or "exactly" one.

Comment: @KurtGödel At least, in the context of the translation of the existential predicate to natural language, we have that $\exists x$ would be read as "there exists an $x$", "there is at least one $x$", or "for some $x$". It would not be entirely incorrect, despite potentially being unclear, to rephrase those once more as "there exists **one** $x$". This isn't necessarily saying "there exists **one and only one** $x$", even though it would be widely read that way.

Comment: On high stakes standardized tests ambiguity is avoided by including phrases such as "at least", "at most", "exactly", "only", "a total of", etc. For example, "John has $6$ apples" is arguably true if John has $8$ apples, and especially for [these types of questions](https://papers.xtremepape.rs/GMAT/gmat-data-sufficiency_tcm55-11057.pdf), the precise intended meaning is absolutely crucial. Also, in such tests one needs to be careful with the use of "some", since in a strict logical sense "for all $x$ we have $P(x)$" can be true (vacuous) along with "for some $x$ we have $P(x)$" being false.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro High stakes standardized tests, and also any other occasions where you might want people to be sure what you mean for whatever reason :)

Comment: If you say "x is one", this would universally be understood and accepted by anyone mathematically-inclined as "x is exactly one", not "x is at least one". And if you combine that with "x humans can fly"... An unqualified "one" may still be somewhat ambiguous how it was used and should probably be avoided, but I wouldn't head in completely the opposite direction in terms of interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned, the negation is "there exists at least one human can fly", while "one human can fly" is negation of "either no human can fly or at least two humans can fly".

In general the negation "there doesn't exist any *being* satisfying some property P" is "there exists at least one being (in particular there may be two or three or more) satisfying property "P".

Answer (score 1):

$\sim(\forall x\in H:\sim F(x))\iff \exists x \in H: F(x)$, where $H$ is the set of all human and $F$ the predicate "can fly". Consequently the negation is "there is a human who can fly".